# How to crop a pdf and preserve links

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript, imagick, pdftk

I have a sample PDF file with crop marks and bleed marks which i am looking for a solution where I can crop them.

The scripts I have tried Imagick, PDFkrop, Ghostscript ,PDFtk,TCPDF which does the job but missing one important thing. After cropping the pdf those software listed above removes the hyperlinks from text.

How can i crop a pdf and preserve the hyperlinks?

Answer (score 0):

Ghostscript won't remove link annotations, though possibly that's not what you mean by hyperlinks.

As I've said on a number of oocasions, Ghostscript doesn't manipulate PDF files, but it can create a new PDF file with alterations.

You don't say what version of Ghostscript you are using, if its very old then you may simply be running up against a bug. The first thing to do is make sure you are using a recent version, ideally the current version. If you are still having problems, post the command line and a link to the PDF file.

Comment: Thank you for your help and direction, I am using latest ghostscript and i used this command to get desired output; gs  -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dQUIET -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -o output.pdf -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=595 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=842 -dFIXEDMEDIA -c "<</PageOffset [-29.5 -29.5]>> setpagedevice"  -f 60-1.pdf ; howevery i have got another problem which is output pdf has got   drop shadow problem ; http://www.lambuka.com/60-1.pdf and out put file is http://www.lambuka.com/output.pdf, any suggestions?

Comment: I can't see a drop shadow problem. If you think there's a bug, best thing to do is report it (bugs.ghostscript.com) Do be sure to attach the original file and be as clear as you can about the problem. I assume this PDF does not exhibit 'hyperlink' problems ? By the way, -dGraphics|lphaBits=4 doesn't generaly do anything with the pdfwrite device.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021, sejda worked for me ([web](https://www.sejda.com/) & desktop versions). In my case I printed a PDF (with hyperlinks) from the browser. Then cropped in Sejda desktop, saved the file and it still had the hyperlinks intact.

There are more detailed steps in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1331717)